# How to make required 'Select' field in drop down list in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i'm new in vuejs. I want to make select element from drop down list required, i tried to add required attribute like the code below.
any idea ?
thx

```html
 <v-select                                
                                    :items="fournisseursByClient"
                                    simple                                                                                                
                                    name="client"                                                             
                                    item-text="idClient"
                                    v-on:change="getSelectedClient"
                                    label="Choisir l'entité juridique"                                  
                                    :menu-props="{ maxWidth: '1000' }"                                                                                    
                                      required>                                     
                                      <template slot='selection' slot-scope='{ item }' >
                                     Vous avez choisi le client : {{ item.client }} ayant un ID : {{ item.idClient }} comme entité juridique
                                      </template>
                                                                         
                                      <template slot='item' slot-scope='{ item }' >                                   
                                       <b>ID</b> : {{ item.idClient }} ||<b>RS</b> : {{ item.client }}|| <b>SIRET</b> : {{ item.siret }} || <b>Adr</b> : {{ item.adresse }} 
                                      </template>
                                      </v-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

use **item-value** and **v-model**

```
v-model="dataVariableToCatchYouItemValue"
item-value="objectAttributeThatYouWantToStore"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule, for example inside data:

```
    new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      rules: {
       select: [v => !!v || 'This is required'] 
      }
    }
```

and on your element you use it like:

```
<v-select
  required
  :rules="rules.select"
></v-select>
```